# Selenium : Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, vpn

I am connected to VPN through my local machine and trying to execute a selenium script on chrome browser then I am getting the following error:

```
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1553947986.711][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1553947990.713][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1553947998.713][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1553948014.713][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, giving up.
[1553948016.724][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1553948020.724][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1553948028.727][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
[1553948044.730][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, giving up.
```

> **This is happening only when i want to execute the script through VPN,
>   without VPN the script is working fine. For firefox browser not
>   getting the above issue**

Comment: Are you using the grid for your execution?

Comment: @supputuri: No we are not using grid

Comment: Seems to be some security app/ firewall setting blocking the connection when you are on VPN. Check if there is any security app runs when connected VPN, try disabling it and see. If that works then reach the VPN Group and ask them to help open the selenium connection.

Comment: No its VPN, I have tried downgrading, upgrading, matching the installed google-chrome the version but didn't working. If its resolved for you, please share.

Comment: @paul : Sure, Will let you know

Comment: Any alternative or you stopped till update?

Comment: @paul  : For time being running the script without vpn from another environment

Comment: @paul : can you try out below solution ? Currently  I am busy in something else

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing this issue since last week. I searched a lot and tried different approaches to solve this problem​. The below code (pseudo code) helped me solve the problem.
My Approach:

1. Run the chromedriver.exe server and check the port number (I have used Process class in my code)
   Check manually first by following below steps:

   - open command prompt
   - navigate to the path where you have your chromedriver
   - run the chromedriver (by just typing >chromedriver )
   - chromedriver server will start running note the port number (in my case 9515)
2. Initialize the driver with the url (http://localhost:portNumber)
3. Usual stuff (maximize, timeouts, navigate to url)
4. Write your test script
5. Close the driver instance (driver.close())
6. Close the process instance (process.destroy())

   `try {
               process = new ProcessBuilder("path of the chromedriver.exe").start();
           } catch (IOException e1) {
               e1.printStackTrace();
           }
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of the chromedriver.exe");
           ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
           try {
               driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:9515"), options);
           } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           // maximize browser
           // delete All Cookies
           // page Load Timeout
           // implicitly Wait
           // navigating to the url
           // run the test scripts
           // close the driver
           // close the process`

Hope it will solve your problem too. If you face any issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--whitelist-ip *");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

You also can specify IP address here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... Will check it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Disabling IPv6 solved this for me. 
On macOS: `networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi`

I also had to remove `::1 localhost` from my hosts file.